What do I call a hook bent in two planes?
I recently built two firewood stands, and I want a convenient way to hold tarps over the firewood. I have decided on carefully placed hooks to hook the tarp's grommets on.
Hooks curved on a single plane are easily available.

I'm after something more sophisticated - hooks curved in two planes.

I have seen these in sailing rigging and as posts to hold up temporary rope fences, but I do not know how to find them.  What is this shape of hook called?

Check out Marine and boat supply stores.  They have all sorts of odd things pertinent to rigging.

My local hardware store carries these but I can't for the life of me remember what they are called.

@RMDman I thought so too, but nothing similar that I could find

I would call it a wire guide, but I don't know of any name more specific than that

Pigtail screw hook is the term you're looking for.  Here's a random example.
They're sometimes called "spiral screw hooks" which is how I found them.

Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!  Your search term turned up a few other aliases too - "bridle ring", "routing ring", and "Q hook"

Insulated versions are used for electric fences, as well. Farm supply shops might have them, insulated or not, in fairly large sizes
